# Set values in a data.frame for columns-names referenced into different column of the data.frame

Tags: r

It's very hard to describe my needs, so I'll put into a visual example.

I've a data.frame that is similar to:

```
foo <- data.frame(
id=c("blah", "foo", "bar"), 
minplayers=c(2,3,1), 
maxplayers=c(4,4,3), 
players1.cash=c(10,20,10), 
players2.cash=c(0,10,10),
players3.cash=c(1,0,0),
players4.cash=c(8,8,9)
)
```

which gives the following:

```
+-----+-----+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|id   | min | max | players1.cash | players2.cash | players3.cash | players4.cash |
+-----+-----+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|blah |  2  |  4  |     10        |      0        |       1       |       8       |
+-----+-----+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|foo  |  3  |  4  |     20        |      10       |       0       |       8       |
+-----+-----+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|bar  |  1  |  3  |     10        |      10       |       0       |       9       |
+-----+-----+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

What I need is to set to NA all the players**n**.cash values for each row if n is *outside* {min,max} interval (for that row). In picture:

```
+-----+-----+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|id   | min | max | players1.cash | players2.cash | players3.cash | players4.cash |
+-----+-----+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|blah |  2  |  4  |     NA        |      0        |       1       |       8       |
+-----+-----+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|foo  |  3  |  4  |     NA        |      NA       |       0       |       8       |
+-----+-----+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|bar  |  1  |  3  |     10        |      10       |       0       |       NA      |
+-----+-----+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

In other words: I just wants the player numbers (1 to 4) to be in the respective boundaries of min/max for each rows. If so, I want to keep the player value, if not, put NA.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match with your description: based on your description, ***all*** your `player*.cash` columns should get `NA` values

Comment: It is not clear why players4.cash is not NA for the first row as it outside the range.  Based on the description, perhaps `t(apply(foo[-1], 1, function(x) {x[3:length(x)][x[3:length(x)] < x[1] | x[3:length(x)] > x[2]] <- NA ; x}))`

Comment: What @Jaap said, either way, I would solve it as follows `indx <- (foo[-c(1:3)] < foo[, 2]) | (foo[-c(1:3)] > foo[, 3]) ; foo[-c(1:3)][indx] <- NA`

Comment: sorry, perhaps I did some mess with the table formatting. players4.cash for blah is not NA because "max" for "blah" is 4

Comment: @akrun how on earth Colonel matched the desired output? It seems I have no idea what the OP is asking for

Comment: @akrun which column?

Comment: @David, the OP just wants the player numbers (1 to 4) to be in the respective boundaries of min/max for each rows. If so, keep the player value, if not, put NA,

Comment: Colonel definitively read my mind! Anyway, you're right when you say that the question was confusing. I've added some better description now, just as a reference

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `vectorized` approach:

```
ix = grep("^players(\\d+)\\.cash", names(foo))
numbers = as.numeric(gsub("^players(\\d+)\\.cash", "\\1", names(foo)[ix]))

m = matrix(numbers, ncol=length(ix), nrow=nrow(foo), byrow=T)
foo[ix][!(m>=foo$minplayers & m<=foo$maxplayers)] <-NA

#> foo
#    id minplayers maxplayers players1.cash players2.cash players3.cash players4.cash
#1 blah          2          4            NA             0             1             8
#2  foo          3          4            NA            NA             0             8
#3  bar          1          3            10            10             0            NA
```

Comment: What sorcery is this?

Comment: the vectorized approach is easier to understand I guess (and faster)

Comment: Hm.. I think I get it (more or less). Still one of the most confusing questions I've seen so far on SO

Comment: BTW, you could just use `col(foo[-c(1:3)])` instead of creating `m` as in `indx <- col(foo[-c(1:3)]) ; foo[-c(1:3)][(indx < foo[, 2]) | (indx > foo[, 3])] <- NA`

Comment: I'm still a bit puzzled about that '4' which is hardcoded and doesn't make the solution general, i must say...

Comment: the solution is now general!

Comment: because we could have had players3, players7, players 9 and players1 for example instead of 1, 2, 3, 4 ...